# How to get summary of TensorFlow model?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm fairly new to this stuff and started doing object detection following [this tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#). I have everything running in the latest version, I have trained and exported models and I am doing object detection just fine.

But I still have no clue how those models in the modelzoo look like under the hood. I have seen summaries of models as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302243/keras-valueerror-dimensions-must-be-equal-issue) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66063808/how-to-generate-a-model-summary-or-plot-the-model-architecture-in-tensorflow-obj) question, but I have no clue where to apply that?

I have tried to open my trained and exported model with

```py
model = tf.saved_model.load(MODEL_PATH)
```

and simply add a

```py
model.summary()
```

command, but it just gives me an error saying

```py
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

So, what am I missing? Do I have to load the trained and not the exported model somehow? And if yes, how should I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way to get something like Keras model.summary in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560313/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-something-like-keras-model-summary-in-tensorflow)

Comment: That looked promising, though I can not get the easy version with inspect_pb.py to run, it just gives me an `google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message` - seems it is meant for TF1, but I am running TF2

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_PATH)
```

Comment: I tried it, just gives me another error:

`python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`